# How upgrade Apache from 2.2.22 to 2.4 on Debian 7 64bit?

Tags: apache, debian

It's possible to upgrade Apache from 2.2.22 to 2.4 on Debian 7 64bit?

I have installed Debian 7 + Apache days ago and it installed Apache 2.2.22..isn't it an old and insecure version?

How can I upgrade to Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.2.22 is the stable distribution for Debian 7

You will need to compile Apache from source code. Debian doesn't automatically update its software in stable (or wheezy); there's a reason why it's the stable distribution but it is possible.

Another way:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
onto /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t sid install apache2
```